# In Inkscape, how do I add a white background in command line mode?

Tags: inkscape, pdf, svg

in short, I tried

```
for f in `ls *.pdf`; do inkscape -z --export-background=ffffff --export-background-opacity=1.0 --export-plain-svg=${f}.svg $f; done
```

It throws no errors, produces SVG files, but doesn't add background to them. Does someone know what's wrong?

It's Inkscape 0.92.4

**UPD** thanks Billy Kerr for pointing towards the solution. I combined his suggestion with use of GNU `sed` to process many files automatically.
It seems like meaningful data in SVG starts from `<defs>` tag, so I just add the rectangle before the first `<defs` occurrence:

```
for f in "*.pdf.svg"; do sed -i '0,/<defs/s/<defs/<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ffffff"\/>\n  <defs/' $f; done
```

which means: sed, please find the first occurrence of a pattern (`0,/pattern`) and substitute it `s/pattern/new string \n pattern/`, writing to the same file (`sed -i` flag).
It looks like a very ad hoc solution, but it works.

Comment: The `ls ` in your for-loop-head is superflous and should be abandoned. Just use "for f in "*.pdf"; do ..."

Comment: @userunknown thanks, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inkscape has no *background* attribute as such, although it does have *pagecolor* which can be set in the document properties (it shows up as "background" in the UI, but appears as "pagecolor" in the XML). The problem however is that the *pagecolor* attribute is not supported in SVG and so it will be lost when you export as plain SVG.

Instead you could try editing the SVG in a text editor to add a white filled rectangle the same size as the canvas, and before (i.e. underneath) the artwork layer.  Sorry, I don't know how to do that with the command line, but hopefully there's enough information here to help you work it out.

for example:

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ffffff"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work on the Inkscape command line currently (0.92.x), so no wonder you don't know how ;-)

Comment: @Moini Then perhaps just copy and pasting the code into the SVGs would be an option for the OP? Obviously it could be rather tedious if there are a lot of SVGs.

Answer (score 3):

Typing `inkscape --help` shows all the commands. One of which being:

```
 -b, --export-background=COLOR              Background color of exported
                                             bitmap (any SVG-supported color
                                             string)
```

As an example, I use LaTeX and other tools a lot of mathematics. A part of the workflow is converting images from SVG to PNG (where I explicitly need a white background). I often use a command like:

```
inkscape MyFile.svg -e MyFile.png -w 300 -b white
```

This simply converts to a png with a width of 300 and with a white background.

As an example, here is my original:

[image: original image]

And here is an export with a RED background:

[image: image with red background]

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I don't consider changing from SVG to a raster image.

Comment: @KarenFidanyan no problem. Just thought to leave my suggestion in case all else fails :)